# ¿Cómo mostrar un MessageBox al terminar la carga de una ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, progressbar

Necesito hacer un programa en c# donde muestre el comportamiento de una ProgressBar para la carga de un MessageBox. Es decir, que cuando finalice la carga en la barra de progreso, aparezca el cuadro de mensaje.

```
private void btncargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmrcargar.Start();
}

private void tmrcargar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.prbmensaje.Increment(10);
    if (prbmensaje.Value==100)
    {
        tmrcargar.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("HOLA MUNDO");
    }
}
```

Si, la idea es crear un progressbar falso para mostrar un messagebox pero cuando ejecuto el programa me sale el messagebox antes de que llegue al maximo el progressbar

Comment: Viendo la pregunta que eliminaste recién, ya tenés un intento código. Por favor ¿podrías agregarlo? Encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta... Por otro lado, ¿la idea es crear una barra de progreso "***falsa***"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me temo que lo que quieres hacer no es facil de conseguir. El problema es que, cuando tu aumentas el valor del progressbar, este incremento no se dibuja inmediatamente, si no que se produce una animación que tarda un tiempo en dibujarse. Por eso ves como el `MessageBox`aparece antes, porque realmente su valor ya es 100 en ese momento pero aun no se ha producido la animación.

Hay algun "hack" que puede simular lo que tu quieres, por ejemplo el código que te pongo a continuación lo que hace es, al llegar al maximo valor del `ProgressBar`, hace una pausa para esperar a que se dibuje la animación:

```
if (prbmensaje.Value == 100)
{
      tmrcargar.Stop();
      for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
           Application.DoEvents();
      }

      MessageBox.Show("HOLA MUNDO");
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a conseguir el efecto deseado.

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo una alternativa con [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), parecerá un poco más compleja pero en cuestión de escalabilidad puede ser lo mejor.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); //se ejecuta el bw
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i =0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i); //reporta progreso
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);//simula una tarea de larga duración
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value=e.ProgressPercentage; //recibe el progreso y actualiza al progressbar
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"HOLA MUNDO");//al finalizar el bw se muestra el mensaje
    }
```

Saludos

Comment: Esta respuesta no resuelve el problema. Tal y como le he dicho a @sstan, he probado tu codigo y no funciona correctamente. El messagebox se lanza antes de completarse el progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de lograr esto, y que está al día con los últimos adelantos de C#, es al usar `async/await`. Una vez que entiendes como funciona, el código es mas sencillo que usar otras opciones como `BackgroundWorker`, y no requiere hacks como el usar pausas articificiales o usar `Application.DoEvents`, que puede llegar a ser problemático si no se usa correctamente.

Lo único que sí te sugiero es que no uses `prbmensaje.Value==100` para determinar si el trabajo está acabado.  Mas bien, el código que efectua el trabajo debería saber cuando no hay mas que hacer, independientemente del progress bar.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo se puede hacer. Nota que no hay necesidad de un timer.

```
private async void btncargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(
        i => {
            // Hack para evitar el problema de la animación muy lenta.
            prbmensaje.Maximum++;
            prbmensaje.Value = i + 1;
            prbmensaje.Value = i;
            prbmensaje.Maximum--;
        });

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            progress.Report(i * 10);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // En vez de un timer, ajusta el sleep aquí si quieres simular el tiempo requerido para efectuar cierto trabajo
        }
    });

    MessageBox.Show("Hola mundo");
}
```

**EDIT**: En efecto, aunque el código trabaja exactamente como debería, la animación del progress bar en sí puede tomar mas tiempo de la cuenta.  Eso es un problema conocido, y del cual se habla [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462978/progress-bar-value-is-not-synchronized-with-what-gets-rendered-in-windows-7). Modifiqué mi respuesta para reflejar el "hack" propuesto en aquella otra pregunta.

Comment: Yo he probado tu codigo y no funciona correctamente. Prueba a cambiar el Sleep de 1000 a 100, y verás como el messagebox se lanza antes de completarse el progressbar

Comment: @Pikoh: Tienes toda la razon. Despues de investigar el asunto un poco mas, agregué mas detalles en mi respuesta que trata el asunto y una manera alternativa de arreglar el problema.